# Logstash with RabbitMQ - Small Message rates (deliver / get | ack)

Tags: elasticsearch, rabbitmq, logstash

i using Rabbitmq in my system. (two node and HA queue)
I have 2 LS-Forwarder, 2 LS-Indexer (8GBRam, 8Core) and 3 Node in ES (32GB, 16Core)

I check queue in RabbitMQ and get isssue :

Imcoming 5k events/document per second and deliver / get is 600 ~ 2000 events/doc per second only.

And after 30min, i have 2M document queued in RabbitMQ.

I increae thread up to 400 / LS-Indexer to RabitMQ. (Consumers =800).

but Message rates (deliver / get) ~2500 docs/events maximum. ack ~1500

So how to increase Message rates (deliver / get) ??

[image: Queue on RabbitMQ]

Comment: Can you show the relevant logstash config files?

Comment: Here is my config LS   [LS-config](http://pastebin.com/vByGmgSq)

Comment: Have you tried to add [more workers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-workers) to your `elasticsearch` output?

Comment: i'm trying. and i have one question: my client (server install beat) connected logstash. but i don't see anything sent to logstash -> RabbitMQ. But when i restart service (filebeat, winlogbeat) on server,  i see log